# bibtex "type=conference"

Tags: biblatex

I would like to print separately articles and conference proceedings.

I have the following Latex code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lib.bib}
\begin{document}
My articles
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none, type=article]
My conferences
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none, type=conference]
\end{document}
```

and the lib.bib file

```
@article{article1,
    author =       "author1",
    title =        "title1",
    journal =       "journal1",
    year =          "2007",
    url =           "library.com/334"
}

@conference{conference2,
    author =       "W",
    booktitle =    "bookt",
    title =        "title2",
    year =          "2008"
}
```

However, the type

```
conference
```

seems not to be picked up:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Type 'conference' not found on input line 11.
```

Any problem?

Comment: Try `inproceedings`. Maybe it doesn't like your using an alias.

Comment: You should only need one `\nocite{*}`. There is no point in not citing anything twice.

Comment: From the [`biblatex` documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=12): "Bibliography styles will see the entry type the alias points to, not the alias name." So I guess @cfr is right, the bibliography style "sees" `@conference` as `@inproceedings`.

Comment: You can probably just change the call to `type=inproceedings`. You can probably leave `@conference` in the `.bib` file. As I understand it, `@conference` disappears when the data is processed by the backend.

Comment: @cfr You should write that as an answer.

Comment: commenting the other \nocite{*} had no effect

Comment: changing `conference` to `inproceedings` seems to work.

Comment: @Viesturs Commenting the second `\nocite{*}` won't get you a bibliography, but it is necessary to get rid of the error BibTeX gives you when compiling your example!

Comment: @hooy Done :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems. The first is that BibTeX gives an error when processing your example because it tries to include everything twice. Removing one of the `\nocite{*}`s resolves this.

The second is that BibTeX 'resolves' `@conference` to the target of this alias, which is `@inproceedings`. So, from Biblatex's perspective, there are no entries of type `conference` cited.

Here's the relevant excerpt from the `.bbl` file after processing with BibTeX:

```
  \entry{conference2}{inproceedings}{}
    \name{author}{1}{}{%
      {{hash=W}{%
         family={W},
         familyi={W},
      }}%
    }
    \strng{namehash}{W1}
    \strng{fullhash}{W1}
    \field{labelnamesource}{author}
    \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
    \field{sortinit}{W}
    \field{sortinithash}{W}
    \field{booktitle}{bookt}
    \field{title}{title2}
    \field{year}{2008}
  \endentry
```

Note that `@conference` in the `.bib` has become type `inproceedings` in the `.bbl`. Hence, Biblatex produces an empty bibliography for the `conference` type listing.

The solution is to simply use `type=inproceedings`. There is no need to alter the data in the `.bib` file as `@conference` disappears before Biblatex sees the entry.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article1,
    author =       "author1",
    title =        "title1",
    journal =       "journal1",
    year =          "2007",
    url =           "library.com/334"
}

@conference{conference2,
    author =       "W",
    booktitle =    "bookt",
    title =        "title2",
    year =          "2008"
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
My articles
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none, type=article]
My conferences
\printbibliography[heading=none, type=inproceedings]
\end{document}
```

[image: bibliographies by non-aliased type]